# How to set Up a Cron Job

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am trying to set up the cron job, can't seem to get it to work.
I keep getting invalid user/password.
I am trying the HTTP method.
I am using WordPress
I am on a shared server.

Comment: Are you struggling with cron generally here?  Like via commandline you type `crontab -e` and if you don't have commandline access maybe your cpanel has a cron interface?  If neither of those then you'd have to ask your hosting company for support.  As far as "invalid user/password".... I wonder if there are more details you could provide that would make it easier for someone to help...?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SE! Can you install cv?  If so, I find that the most straightforward for cron. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cv

For the HTTP method, does the user/password work when logging in via GUI?  Does it work with curl or wget? (See same doc)  Check that works before adding the complications of cron itself.